# Some orders come in without email

Tags: magento-1.8, php

I have a strange problem in Magento store, some orders come in without email.
[image: order without email]

As you can see on screen, such orders marked as Guest and group General, which basically refers to registered customers. How could this happen? 
This issue happens on the production server and I can't reproduce it myself.

I've tried making orders when logged with a different phone number or when not logged in but with the same email. Nothing works.

We using IWD/OPC plugin on checkout, but I can't figure out what code cause the problem.

Maybe someone has the same problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: Also discovered that such orders stored in db (sales_flat_order table) without any reference to customer, all columns, such as customer_id, customer_email, customer_firstname, customer_lastname are NULL. BUT in Admin Panel->Order Details-> Billing and Shipping addresses sections contains information about customer(his name, phone etc).